# JavaScript performance of || operator to instantiate a variable

Tags: javascript, performance, shorthand

Just a quick question that I can't seem to find a reliable source for. I always use the `||` operator for shorthand `undefined` checks, like

```
myVar = myVar || {};
```

But I'm wondering if this means it will reassign myVar if it exists? And hence if it would be better, from a performance point of view, to expand this to an `if` statement as such:

```
if(!myVar) myVar = {};
```

Many thanks in advance for clearing this up!

Comment: Not worth worrying about IMO, just use what's more convenient.

Comment: What's up with all those "what is faster/more efficient?" questions when it comes to completely irrelevant sections of code? It really doesn't matter if one of the two takes 200 cycles more of one CPU core. That core is doing mostly nothing the other 2,000,000,000 cycles there are in one second anyway.

Comment: **Micro optimization is the root of all evil and is not worth it.** Go with what *you* find easiest to read.

Comment: Thanks guys, @elclanrs can you put that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine that you would run this more than a few times at runtime. It will never be a problem.

If this is in hot function then you are screwed anyway because implicit/optional stuff is intuitively very bad. I cannot imagine you have a hot function that needs to do this. You are probably establishing classes or modules - you could run a loop for 100000 times additionally and not notice anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about jsPerf? I cant check it myself (mobile phone)
http://jsperf.com/browse

Comment: Here's your jsperf: http://jsperf.com/var-initialization-with-or-vs-if/2 -- Conclusion: there's absolutely no difference between them. Sometimes one is faster, sometimes other is. Go with whatever is more readable to you.